# Move Divs with up and down links Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have many div with the same class , i need found a way to move theme up and down when oi press up link or down link :( !!!

```
  <div class="Container" id="Con1">
    <div><a>Up</a><a>Down</a></div>
    Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome 
textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text
    </div>

    <div class="Container" id="Con1">
    <div><a>Up</a><a>Down</a></div>
    Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome
 textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text
    </div>

 <div class="Container" id="Con3">
    <div><a>Up</a><a>Down</a></div>
    Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome
 textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text
    </div>
```

Jquery : some idea but not good for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected=0;

    $("#items div").click(function() {
        selected= $(this).index();
    });

     $("#up").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    });

     $("#down").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: ID's should also be unique.

Comment: Hi, have you written any actual jQuery which didn't work?

Comment: @ Ynhockey  Code is submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Query `before()` and `after()`

First of all a template:

```
<div class="Container" id="Con1">
    <div><a href="javascript: void(0);" class="up">Up</a><a  href="javascript: void(0);" class="down">Down</a></div>
    Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome
    textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text
</div>
```

Then the click handlers

```
$(".up").click(function(e){
   var parent = $(this).parent(".Container");
   if (parent.prev().length > 0)
   {
        parent.prev().before(parent);
   }
   e.preventDefault();
});

 $(".down").click(function(e){
     var parent = $(this).parent(".Container");
     if (parent.next().length > 0)
     {
          parent.next().after(parent );
     }
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

How is this working, a break down:

1. I've added a class to the `a` elements called `up` or `down`. I also added a href that runs a JavaScript code `void`. It returns nothing, but causes the `a` element to behave as a link. You need to change all your `divs` to this format. And as the comments suggested only use **unique** ids!
2. Used jQuery selectors to select all `up` and `down` classes and attach an `event handler` (*click*) to it.
3. Within this event handler I request the source element with `this`. This refers to the `a`. The `a` is a grandchild of it's container `div`.
     `div > div > a`.
   Therefor I need to call `parent('.Container')`. This function will go up the DOM tree until the first parent with the class name `Container` is found.
4. Now the next funky bit checks if there is an element next to it. By down we look for a sibling after the current div, by up we look for it before. If there is an element we can move on and position the element before or after it depending on the movement.

Comment: @MohamedSamy I've updated it entirely. It now reflects your coding with improvements and a step by step explanation. Use http://api.jquery.com it's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is you have multiple divs w/ the same ID (Con1). Also your ID's and class names should be lower-cased. Another is you need `href` attribute on your anchor tags.

You also need a wrapper to contain the sections that you'll be moving

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="container" id="con1">
       <div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0); class="up">Up</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0); class="down">Down</a>
       </div>
   Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome 
   </div>

   <div class="container" id="con2">
       <div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0); class="up">Up</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0); class="down">Down</a>
       </div>
   Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome 
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#wrapper').on('click','a', function(e) {
     var $this = $(this);
     var $container = $this.closest('.container');
     var count = $('#wrapper').find('.container').length;

     if ($this.hasClass('up')) {
         // check to see if we're on the top level - if we are, do nothing
         if (!$container.index() == 0) {
              $('#wrapper').prepend($container);
         }
     }
     else {  // class id "down"
         if (count != $container.index() - 1) {
              $('#wrapper').append($container);
         }
     }
});
```